# Is it possible to configure eclipse ee to make autocomplete in javascript code in js files in a java project?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm developing a web application on java and I have a number of js files there.
Is it possible to configure eclipse ee to make autocomplete in javascript code in js files in a java project?

How is it possible, if it's possible?

Comment: Why do you have js files in a Java project?

Comment: It's a web application, so I have js files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the project (in the Project or Package Explorer), and from the Configure menu, make it a JavaScript project as well.  This won't remove any Java features from the project, it will simply make it able to have the features of a JavaScript project at the same time.

Comment: in configure menu I have "convert to javascript project" are sure this won't remove any java-specific features? I vaguely remember that I tried this once. After I did that in configure menu appeared "convert to Java project" and I assumed that conversions removes java-specific features.

Comment: Correct, it will NOT remove any Java features.

Comment: thanks, it's worked. I hope eclipse won't screw up. Because I remember that last time when I experimented with project configuration changes, i.e. changing "nature" of project, it started behave strangely and I had to create project anew or reinstall eclipse.

Comment: This added the nature and configuration files into the .setting folder of the project. It doesn't change existing ones, not should anything on that menu.

Comment: Hmm, that should have been "nor should anything on that menu."